# word or phrase for describing one that has much opportunities

Tags: analogy, synonyms

Take "folly" for example, there is the term "fool" or "foolish" for the individual that does that folly, and the term "foolishness" that is the quality of being foolish or doing folly.
I am looking for words or phrases that can be applied to "opportunities" as of *folly*, that mean:

1. what the person that has much opportunities is called; Analogy: "fool" or "foolish"
2. the quality of having opportunities; Analogy: "foolishness"

keep in mind that *folly, fool, foolish, foolishness* are all in the same family of words.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There's the derivation ***opportunistic*** for someone who (unfairly) *exploits* opportunities. But I doubt there are any terms based on that root with the meaning *having many opportunities (whether taken advantage of or not).* The standard concept in this area is that of being in a  ***privileged position*** (having opportunities that are denied to others).

Comment: they are in an opportune situation

Comment: @aparente001: Why would you say that? It's a *comment*, not an answer, so it doesn't need to "get to" whatever OP wants to know. But the *purpose* of my comment was to point out that 1) The "family of words" centred around ***opportunity*** doesn't include any relating to a person having many opportunities, and 2) the *concept* OP is getting at isn't easily/naturally expressed in English. Sure, I can say *The world is his oyster,* but the "natural" adjectives in that general area are things like *He's privileged* or *He's lucky*, which aren't quite the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thank you for clarifying.  I take it you were letting OP know that the *only* word in the family is *opportunistic* which unfortunately doesn't come close to what OP was looking for.  I'm sorry I didn't understand that the first time.

Comment: @aparente001: Effectively, yes. There's also ***opportune***, with synonyms including *auspicious, propitious, favourable, advantageous, heaven-sent, golden, good, right, lucky, happy, fortunate, benign, providential, felicitous*, but that's not an attribute we use for *people* - it's only applied to *[favourable] circumstances*. I assume the concept of ***social mobility*** is central to the "word family" OP seeks, but you couldn't even rely on, say, *John is socially mobile* being correctly interpreted (maybe he just has multiple non-overlapping circles of friends all of his social class).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think opportunities can land one's way even without pre-existing social mobility.  But then I am in the U.S.  Maybe you're in the UK and maybe it's a bit different there, I don't know.  If you were saying that opportunities can result in social mobility, I would agree.

Comment: @aparente001: Well, they do say America is the land of opportunity, so "anyone can become president". But in practice nearly all US presidents (like *French* presidents) are drawn from a small pool of incredibly wealthy families. Us Brits have never thought "anyone can be Queen" (i.e. - Head of State) except in fairy stories, but we do occasionally elect relatively "ordinary" people to the post of Prime Minister. My point was we normally assume "privileged" people do in fact *exploit* their opportunities, not simply *have [good] options available* - which may make a difference in OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have to be a little careful here not to step on any national toes, I think!  I know very little about social mobility in Britain or Europe in general; my German spouse is the only member of the extended family to attend college, and turned out to be a total fluke, getting a PhD and doing three postdocs.  That gives me exactly ONE data point for all of Europe.  In the U.S. if we look at the Kennedys and the Bushes, for example, we would arrive at a different picture than if we look at some others; there's a lot more to social mobility than the presidency....

Comment: There is no shortage of people in the U.S. who have made anything of themselves despite opportunities being available -- but aren't we getting off track?  OP just wants an adjective related to *opportunity*.

Answer (score 1):

When you have opportunities, you are *lucky*, in other words, you are *fortunate*.

> what the person that has much opportunities is called; Analogy: "fool" or "foolish"

**Fortunate**

> the quality of having opportunities; Analogy: "foolishness"

**Good fortune**

See, for example, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fortune

Answer (score 0):

**lot of promise**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lot+of+promise)

> much promise for the future. (*Typically: have ~; show ~.) Sally is
>   quite young, but she has a lot of promise. This bush is small, but it
>   shows a lot of promise.

Answer (score -1):

You could say use the currently very fashionable word "privileged":

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/privilege

> a. A special advantage, immunity, permission, right, or benefit granted to or enjoyed by an individual, class, or caste.

This is often applied to people who have more opportunities than most, for example because of their parents' wealth or social connections.